# Are there infinitely many integer solutions to $a^4+b^4-c^4=N$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there non-zero integer $N$ such that

$$ a^4+b^4-c^4=N \qquad (1)$$

has infinitely many integer solutions $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b \ne \pm c$?

(1) is a surface, so possible approach is to find genus 0 curve on it
with infinitely many integral points.

Partial argument for positive answer is similar equation is possible
over larger ring: $a^4+b^4+c^4=18$ over $\mathbb{Z}[i],i^2=-1$.

Let $a= x - y - 1 ,b= 2*y + 2 ,c= -x - y - 1$. Then
$a^4+b^4+c^4=18 + q_1(x,y) q_2(x,y)$ where $q_1=x^2 + 3*y^2 + 6*y$.
When $q_1=0$ we have solution and this is possible infinitely often
over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Not necessarily. First, there are a few obvious congruence obstructions, such as $N \equiv 3 \mod{8}$. More to the point, it can be shown that a zero density of integers $N$ are thus represented.

Comment: Zero density seems like a hard theorem because conceivably a positive fraction of $N$ could allow solutions with dramatic cancellation (though we expect the number of representable $x < N$ to grow only as $x^{3/4 + o(1)}$).

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov I am asking for existence of single N with infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @joro: Thanks for your edit! This is now a different question. I would a guess a negative answer. Incidentally you do not need to add the condition that $a,b \neq  \pm c$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Good point! Thinking about this I could not locate any literature that takes care of the zero density question, let alone of the exact asymptotics of the number of representable $N$. I'd be interested to see a reference that implies this. Odoni (*On the norms of algebraic integers*, Mathematika, 1975) takes care of the norm form equations, which are 'critical' (number of variables = degree). Here we have a supercritical case in more than two variables, on which not much appears to be known in general (at least reg. asymptotics), judging from the reference I give in the next cmt.:

Comment: @joro: A similar question, but in the 'critical' rather than in your 'supercritical' case, was studied in a recent paper by Ghosh and Sarnak: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.06712.pdf (*Integral points on Markoff type cubic surfaces*). Its introduction raises exactly this kind of question. In the supercritical case, Vojta's conjecture prescribes that the solutions to $F(\mathbf{x}) = N$, for any $N$, are never Zariski-dense. Your question might be difficult to answer without assuming any such conjecture.

Comment: . . . and even if one does assume the conjecture, because there's still the possibility of a rational curve with only one or two poles on the surface that yields infinitely many integer solutions.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Very similar equation has infinitely many solutions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297289/infinitely-many-integer-solutions-to-x4y4-18z4-16

Comment: @joro That construction is of course in accordance with the Vojta conjecture, according to which all solutions lie in a lower dimensional algebraic subvariety (the relation $X-Y = 2$ in Henri Cohen's solution to your new question). I was guessing that there are no such relations in your older equation (which I haven't given a serious thought, and in any case I could be wrong with my guess).